# How to implement a counter in MySQL that responds to changes in another column?

Tags: mysql

There is a table "**Table1"** which contains a variety of information on the Bank's Customers (including their service channel) by time intervals (**Start_DT** – **End_DT**).
From this table, you need to select all the data and another calculation column "Key" with an increasing key, which increases for each Client with each change of its service channel.

Example of a basic request:

```
SELECT
  CLIENT_ID, START_DT, END_DT, CHANNEL, «???» AS 'KEY'
FROM
  Table1
WHERE 
  CLIENT_ID IN(100, 101)
ORDER BY
  CLIENT_ID, START_DT DESC
```

Example of the final table:

| CLIENT_ID | START_DT | END_DT | CHANNEL | KEY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2016/11/17 | 2016/12/31 | Mass | 1 |
| 100 | 2016/10/10 | 2016/11/16 | Mass | 1 |
| 101 | 2016/11/13 | 2016/12/31 | Mass | 3 |
| 101 | 2016/11/12 | 2016/11/12 | Prem | 2 |
| 101 | 2016/11/08 | 2016/11/11 | Mass | 1 |
| 101 | 2016/10/13 | 2016/11/07 | Mass | 1 |

Comment: What version of MySQL? Run `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: VERSION()
8.0.27

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/q8sWlCa8

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to describe what exactly the task is. From this table, you need to select all the data  and another calculation column "Key" with an increasing key, which increases for each Client with each change of its service channel.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title provides no information about the issue you're having. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey meaning about the subject of your post to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title provides zero information. You've also not clearly described the problem at all - the small addition you made in the comments is useless, as that info should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) [`LAG(CHANNEL)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) to return the `CHANNEL` from the row that precedes the current row within its partition. We can then use `SUM()` as a counter, incrementing the `KEY` each time `CHANNEL` is not equal to `PREV_CHANNEL`:

```
SELECT ID, CLIENT_ID, START_DT, END_DT, CHANNEL,
    SUM(NOT (PREV_CHANNEL <=> CHANNEL)) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY START_DT ASC) AS `KEY`
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LAG(CHANNEL) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY START_DT ASC) AS PREV_CHANNEL
    FROM Table1
) t
ORDER BY CLIENT_ID DESC, START_DT DESC
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IUb0Rxd-)

Docs for [<=>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)